# Significance of specific digit in non-terminating number

Tags: conventions, error-analysis

I was wondering whether the post-decimal 0 in 0.0999... is significant or not. Since it's a non-terminating number and we consequently know every single digit in it, I assume it could be called an exact number, and that by definition every digit to the right of and including the left-most 9 would be significant, resulting in an infinite number of significant figures. The post-decimal 0 still wouldn't be significant here, though.

But then 0.0999... is the same as 0.100..., and considering it in that form, every digit to the right of the one - including it - would be significant.

Is this correct? While representing the number in two ways and specifying the significance in their digits separately doesn't seem too wrong, I'm not sure if that's the accepted convention (if there is one). Moreover, this way, you can't really tell if the 'first decimal digit' in 0.0999... is significant or not.

---

I realize that this is about identifying significant figures in an exact number and is thus probably useless for all practical purposes, but I'm still asking, if only for technical (or semantic?) interest.

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).

Answer (score 0):

The “significant figures” approach is a rough heuristic for estimating precision and imprecision.  Suppose you and I are doing the same experiment and we’re told to report our result to “two significant figures.” You measure $0.987$ and round your result to $0.99 \pm 0.01$.  I measure $1.012$ and round my result … to $1.0 \pm 0.1$?  Is my result magically ten times less precise than yours, because it happened to be 3% larger?  Like hell it is.  I’m rounding mine to $1.01\pm0.01$, regardless of the dumb instructions.

One modification is to keep an “extra” significant digit if the leading digit is a one. Or perhaps an extra digit if the leading digit is a one or a two. Or [this more complicated recipe](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2021/reviews/rpp2020-rev-rpp-intro.pdf) (skip to $\S$5.3) for deciding how many errors to report *in an uncertainty estimate*.  There is also guidance about keeping track of an extra significant digit, a “guard digit,” in a long calculation, to reduce the impact of intermediate rounding on your final result.

In your case the question is really moot, because you remove insignificant figures by rounding, rather than by truncation.  It’s the case that the repeating decimal $0.\bar 9$ is *exactly* equal to $1.0$; it’s also the case that the non-repeating decimal $0.99984$ is equal to $1.000$ to four (unguarded) significant figures.